# Initialise DB in Flask

Tags: python, flask

I have read the Flask documentation and Python documentation to try to understand what these codes do. I know that it is initialise the Database but would like to know in very detail and with normal language, easy language for beginner.

Can anyone please explain me about this?

```
import sqlite3
from contextlib import closing

DATABASE = 'flaskr.db'

def connect_db():
    return sqlite3.connect(app.config[’DATABASE’])


def init_db():
    with closing(connect_db()) as db:
        with app.open_resource(’schema.sql’, mode=’r’) as f:
            db.cursor().executescript(f.read())
        db.commit()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import sqlite3
```

Imports Data base connectors

```
from contextlib import closing
```

No idea why its used.
[Documentetion here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/contextlib.html)

```
DATABASE = 'flaskr.db'
```

Defines database,in this case it is a db file.

```
def connect_db():
    return sqlite3.connect(app.config[’DATABASE’])
```

Connect DB method which returns a sqlite3 connection, using sqlite3 import and invoking connect() on it.
Hint: try >>> dir(sqlite3) after importing in your python console

```
def init_db():
  with closing(connect_db()) as db:
    with app.open_resource(’schema.sql’, mode=’r’) as f:
        db.cursor().executescript(f.read())
    db.commit()
```

Initialize database method, it takes a schema.sql and executes it on DB by f.read method.
After executing you need to commit changes to db, hence db.commit()

You can find it explained clearly [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html)

Comment: `contextlib.closing` is used so that `init_db` can use it rather than the more verbose `try: db = connect_db() try: f = app.open_resource(...) # snip finally: f.close() finally: db.close()`